# PHP - AdaptivePaymentsService::pay() - always returns error: 520002

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to do a very simple payment with Paypal, which seemed to be very simple from the examples. But all I get is a very uninformative "internal error" / 520002 response :(.

```
$config = array(
                'mode' => 'sandbox',
                'acct1.UserName' => 'myUsername',
                'acct1.Password' => 'myPassword',
                'acct1.Signature' => "mySignature"
                );
$service = new AdaptivePaymentsService($config);

$requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");

$receiver = new Receiver();
$receiver->email = "aValidEmailAddress@test.net";
$receiver->amount = 4;
$receiverList = new ReceiverList(array($receiver));


$payRequest = new PayRequest($requestEnvelope, "PAY", "http://somehost/cancel", "EUR", $receiverList, "http://somehost/return");
$payRequest->senderEmail = "anotherValidEmailAddress@test.net";
$payRequest->ipnNotificationUrl = "http://somehost/ipn2";

$response = $service->pay($payRequest);
```

response:

```
{
"responseEnvelope":
{
"timestamp":"2014-12-27T21:58:18.816-08:00",
"ack":"Failure",
"correlationId":"5da19d03caba3",
"build":"13414382"
},
"payKey":null,
"paymentExecStatus":null,
"payErrorList":null,
"paymentInfoList":null,
"sender":null,
"defaultFundingPlan":null,
"warningDataList":null,
"error":
[
{
"errorId":"520002",
"domain":"PLATFORM",
"subdomain":"Application",
"severity":"Error",
"category":"Application",
"message":"Internal Error",
"exceptionId":null,
"parameter":null
}
]
}
```

The credentials seem to be right, as I seemingly managed to get past the authentication related errors.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is the original code I run from my local Webserver.
I just changed the credentials and personal data to garbage.

Already tried some things, like a different currency, no sender email, etc. (like in the example code from Paypal)

Cheers!

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I am having this exact problem. Please help if anyone knows about this error.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the above code the only thing that I can see missing is APPLICATION ID :

**"X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID" .**

If you are in sandbox mode you need to pass the default app id which is : **APP-80W284485P519543T**

You need to make sure that you are passing it in your code also. You can refer a sample request at the below url :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/